# When returning a private member, is the returned value a direct reference to the member or a separate copy?

Tags: java, access-modifiers

To clarify this, consider the following code:

```
public class Foo {
    private Object thing;

    public Foo() { ... }

    public Object getThing() {
        return this.thing;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar() { ... }

    public Object makeNewThing() { ... }

    public void changeThing() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Object thing = foo.getThing();
        thing = makeNewThing();
    }
}
```

When `Bar` <strike>mutates</strike> modifies the value of the `Object` it receives from `foo.getThing()`, is the original private member within `foo` <strike>mutated</strike> modified?

edit: some words

Comment: Reference is number (integer) which JVM uses to identify an object. Reference variable will hold returned value like 123 because that would happen to be object identifier of JVM. Each variable has its own reserved space so that value is copied to that space. If you have two reference variables holding same reference they both can modify same object.

Comment: mutation of object is done via references using `.` dot operator and invoking the *mutator* methods (if available and accessible) or directly changing the property (if available and accessible.)  `=` changes the object to which a particular reference was referring to.

Comment: Shouldn't last statement include `makeNewThing` instead of `makeThing`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is the original private member within foo mutated?

No, because you are assigning something new to the variable `thing` in `changeThing`, not mutating the object. If you *did* mutate the object, the mutation will reflect in the private member as well.

Note that `getThing` *will* return the original object referenced by `Foo.thing`, *not* a copy of it.

Since in your code, `thing` is of type `Object`, this behaviour is a little hard to see. I will use a mutable class `Baz` to demonstrate this:

```
public class Baz {
    public int x = 0;
}

public class Foo {
    private Baz thing;

    public Foo() { thing = new Baz(); }

    public Baz getThing() {
        return this.thing;
    }
}

public class Bar {
    public Bar() { ... }

    public Object makeNewThing() { ... }

    public void changeThing() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        Baz thing = foo.getThing();
        thing.x = 10;
        System.out.println(foo.thing); // this will print 10, not 0
    }
}
```

So to avoid any modifications to `Foo.thing`, you can either:

- Create a copy of `thing` manually and return it (Java won't do the copying automatically for you!) or,
- Make the type of `thing` immutable

Comment: Great answer, thanks. I should've said 'modified' instead of 'mutated'; the original post has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

The thing returned by `getThing()` is a **reference** to the private variable `thing`

If you need to modify it, use `foo.getThing().doSomeMethod()`

What you currently do in `changeThing`: grab a reference to `foo`s thing and assign it to the method variable `thing`. Then you assign to the variable `thing` a completely different thing. This **does not** change anything inside the instance `foo`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the original member within foo is mutated if you *actually* mutate the object. Currently you are simply reassigning the variable you hold which doesn't perform any action on the object itself.

Consider this

```
public class Foo {
    private FooInner thing = new FooInner();

    public FooInner getThing() {
        return this.thing;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(thing.i);
    }

    class FooInner{
        int i = 0;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        System.out.println(foo); //Prints 0 

        FooInner thing = foo.getThing();
        thing.i = 10;

        System.out.println(foo); //Prints 10

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see comments:

```
public class Foo {
    private Object thing;

    //constructor to create an Foo-Object-Instance
    public Foo() { ... }

    //method to return a characteristic of a Foo-Object, 
    //whereas this characteristic is an object, not a primitive data type
    public Object getThing() {
        return this.thing;
    }
}

public class Bar {

    //constructor to create an Bar-Object-Instance
    public Bar() { ... }

    //returns an object and does whatever it's supposed to do within the { ... }
    //I wonder how's object connected to bar?
    public Object makeNewThing() { ... }

    public void changeThing() {
        //is Foo a subtype of Bar?

        //creating a Foo-Class-Instance (object)
        //that contains a variable Object (which is not the data as it would be with
        //primitive data types, but a reference to the data)
        Foo foo = new Foo();

        //and with "foo.getThing()" you get the reference ("address") 
        //of the Object foo's characteristic "thing" (which is an object 
        //as well, so you copy the address to the data) and add it to the 
        //new "Object thing", which
        //you have declared on the left side of the =

        //so you have two object variables pointing/with reference to the same data
        Object thing = foo.getThing();
        //when you use makeAnewThing - whatever stands in there - to change the 
        //object ("thing") variables data, then the data of the object will 
        //be changed if so stated in the { } and
        //hence basically the thing-object (or "variable") 
        //within the foo-object as well, 
        //because both variable names are pointing to the same data

        thing = makeThing();
    }
}
```

There might be a confusion, because you name both "thing", i. e. the object thing declared outside foo-object and the object-variable "thing" within foo-class.

Important is the difference between objects and primitive data types, whereas object variables or names like "String objectname" or "Object foo" contain the reference to the data:

```
//declare an object named abs, which does not point to data
Object abc;
//declare an object named def and (right side of =) initiate it with data or variable or whatever the constructor says what's to be done
Object def = new Object();
//copy the reference ("address" of def-Object) to abc
abc = def;
//now we have one data thingi with two references to it, i. e. abc and def
```

If you now add changes to abc, then the changes will, when stated in the method, be added to the data abc is pointed to. If you then use something like def.getData(), the changed data will be returned, as both, abc and def, point to the same data.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you should understand the concept of reference types...

Consider the following code :
Foo f = new Foo();

This is, in fact, two orders

1, new foo() => it creates a foo in part of memory called heap, it is your real var or content

2, Foo f => the above var(content) address put in f. so f is a reference to content.

In your code, when you return this.thing, in fact, you return a reference or address of an object.

and when you write :

foo.getThing() return the thing that is in Foo class and it is a reference or pointer to an object and then

Object thing = foo.getThing();

put the address of Foo's thing in another reference named thing.
And it means that both of them are pointing to the same content...